# Snowflake. How to check if the sub-array is presented in another array?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to check if all the items from one array are presented in another array.
I've been looking through Snowflake docs but can't find any good approach.
For example in PostgreSQL it's easily solved by `<@` (i.e. `ARRAY[2,7] <@ ARRAY[1,7,4,2,6]`).
Any ideas on how to solve it gracefully without ugly hacks? Thanks!

Comment: `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html

Comment: No. It's to check if 1 item is presented in the array, but I want to find out if the array items are presented in another array.
P.S. I don't want to generate numerous ARRAY_CONTAINS conditions for every item joined by AND.

Comment: How about this select array_intersection(array_construct(2,7), 
                          array_construct(1,7,4,2,6));

Comment: I thought about it, in fact, it returns another array of items presented in both arrays.
But I want to get the boolean result (TRUE if all the items of, say, the left array are presented in the right array, otherwise FALSE). Sure, I might as well take this result and check, for example, the length of the left array and the length of the `array_intersection` result, I'm sure it would work, but it's kind of an ugly workaround. That's why I'm looking for a graceful, pretty solution here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic with `ARRAY_INTERSECTION` and size could be wrapped with UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_array_subarray (arr1 ARRAY, arr2 ARRAY)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
  AS 'ARRAY_SIZE(ARRAY_INTERSECTION(arr1,arr2)) = ARRAY_SIZE(arr1)';
```

Query:

```
SELECT a1, a2, is_array_subarray (a1, a2) AS res
FROM (SELECT ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(2,7), ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1,7,4,2,6) 
      UNION
      SELECT ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(2,7,2), ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1,7,4,2,6) 
     ) AS s(a1, a2);
```

Output:

[image]

(*) The handling of non-unique elements may require refinement depending of needs. Here it requires full match

Comment: It turns out Snowflake doesn't have this feature by default. Ok, in this case using UDF looks good. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to Lukasz Szozda's answer. It's much better to use `ARRAY_SIZE(ARRAY_INTERSECTION(arr1,arr2)) = ARRAY_SIZE(arr1)` as it is, without using UDF because of really high performance impact.
I was playing around with the  2 equal queries but the latter was with the UDF. The time of execution difference was 40ms and 2s.
I decided not to use UDF.